# Rotating logs for Spring Boot running as Linux services

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, centos

I deployed my jar file as a service on centos and it is working good , but i need to rotate my log file , doing so using logrotate did not work as no output was sent to the new log file.

I am using logback and it is logging to file appender so my options are

1- Stop the service from logging the console to log file and use logback 
2- Enable logrotate if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `copytruncate` option in logrotate-config. This works like a charm for me but there is a little drawback as stated in the manpage:

> **copytruncate**
>
> Truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one. It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever. Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost. When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place.